# Weird error message while implementing ValidateAntiForgeryToken in asp.net mvc project production environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing ValidateAntiForgeryToken for my MVC application which is deployed in Azure.

1) I added   @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in Main page.

2) I'm doing send data for Post action by using Jquery $.Post Here is the code

```
   `var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    var url = '/XX/YYYY/';
        $.post(url, { __RequestVerificationToken: token,reportname: reportName},
        function (data) { window.navigate(data.url) }
        );`
```

I'm passing token to server and saw in fiddler , tht Cookie and Hidden variable are passed to server.

3) I attributed the action with   [HttpPost]  & [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

This work perfectly in my DEV environment of azure, but when we move into different envrionment it fails, 
It throws exception ***"A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid "***

I observed the value of hidden variable and value in cookie variable are different. Even the same in my dev environment, but it works in dev environment but not in test. Please suggest how to trouble shoot this exception.

Configuration is same for DEV and TEST azure sites.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trace out my issue by duplicating ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute class into my solution and adding necessary helper methods for this attribute class since most of the classes or sealed or internal. So i have to copy the code and do some modification inorder to work perfectly in my azure envrionment. Basically, Problem is with

```
AntiForgeryData.GetUsername(context.User)
```

This method returns userName has null , so i justed modified to

```
 string currentUsername = AntiForgeryData.GetUsername(context.User) ?? string.Empty;
```

Then it started working perfectly, In Azure the setting of happening lately where in validateAntifogery happen early, So this fixes issue of mine.